# Where can I find articles/books on 2D graphics (how it works etc.)?

Tags: graphics, 2d

After I have been through more intensive C++ studies, I am thinking of giving it a start in my practices of computer game programming. Therefore, I think 2D knowledge (processing images, animating frames, etc.) would be a good place to start. However, I don't seem to find many articles on 2D (mostly 3D), and if found one, it is mostly stuffs like how to use a 2D game engine. I would really want something much more low-level, or "from scratch" ideas.

I want articles/books that would answer something like:

How would I import images into C++? (Let's say, if I want to import jpeg/bmp/etc. file into raw C++ code, what would I do?)

Basically, I just want to have enough low-level knowledge about computer graphics to be able to create something like 2D game engine from scratch.

Comment: If you asked stackexchange how to import images into C++, I bet you'd get a useful answer :)

Answer (score 2):

SDL would be a good place to start. Here is a link to some general articles on beginning 2D game design:
http://lazyfoo.net/articles/index.php

On that same site they have a pretty complete tutorial set that will show you everything you need to know to program a basic 2D game.
http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php

The reason I really like this tutorial is that it really breaks it down for you into readable code. It also introduces how to incorporate OpenGL which is a much more powerful library.